# Joomla installation infinite loop on delete/backup old tables

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, joomla, centos7

Joomla hangs on the first installation task (deletion/backup of old tables)

[image]

In the nginx access log I can see the following requests repeated infinitely:

```
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [29/Jul/2017:04:27:17 +0200] "GET /installation/index.php?tmpl=body&view=install HTTP/1.1" 200 611 "https://example.com/installation/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [29/Jul/2017:04:27:17 +0200] "POST /installation/index.php?task=InstallDatabase_remove HTTP/1.1" 200 361 "https://example.com/installation/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
```

No other errors being displayed or logged.

I'm using a MySQL database on a remote server and CentOS 7 for the Joomla installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue, patch available: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/17248